# Is it possible to run a script from Firebase Functions Shell?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I've been using the Firebase Functions Shell (firebase experimental:functions:shell) and am finding it excellent for testing the firebase database and http listeners.

However it is a little annoying that I have to copy-paste test code in the shell.

Is there any way I can just write some js code in a file and then run the complete file with the Firebase shell? Without copying and pasting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, send your script the the shell's stdin.

```
$ firebase experimental:functions:shell < tests.js
```

Taken from [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/09/testing-functions-locally-with-cloud.html).

You may still have to terminate the shell with ctl-C.  Please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) if you would like to see that change.

Comment: Awesome! And so easy! :-D